# Configure SNMP on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: monitoring, snmp, net-snmp, snmp-trap, snmpd

I need to monitor a system via SNMP and integrate it with zabbix 5.0. I was making some test on my local machine so I installed snmp, snmpd and snmp-mib-downloader on ubuntu 20.04.
I need to monitor all these variables:
[variables to monitor via snmp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByvB5.png)

The problem is that when I try to see some of those variables on my local machine, this happens:

> snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 127.0.0.1 DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::mteHotTrigger.0

And I get:

> DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::mteHotTrigger.0 = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID

Is there a way to change the value of the values of the trigger? Why is it that I cannot see the value of some of those variables?

Comment: Try to run commands like `snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 127.0.0.1 1.3.6` please. You are not supposed to perform WALK operations on a leaf node OID.

Answer (score 0):

The [DISMAN-EVENT-MIB](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2981#section-7) defines the `MAX-ACCESS` for `mteHotTrigger` as `accessible-for-notify`.

From the [SNMPv2-SMI](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2578#section-7.3):

> The value "accessible-for-notify" indicates an object which is accessible only via a notification (e.g., snmpTrapOID [5]).

In other words, this particular value cannot be retrieved using any kind of `GET` request (in fact, if you read the description of that variable, it only makes sense in the context of a notification). You need to set up your local machine to receive SNMP traps (notifications), and configure your managed machine to send traps to it.